# I have a probs with fetch ReactJS, I can't fetch datas in component did mount or in a function

Tags: reactjs, function, react-hooks, fetch

i want to fetch data from movie database on my state, I try with hooks I can't do that, now same probs with the state.

```
     componentDidMount() {

   fetch(jsonUrl)
      .then(response => {
        response.json();
      })
      .then( data => {
        console.log("CDM", data);
      });
  }
```

When I try to fetch inside my ComponentDidMount or inside a function or inside useEffect Hooks, it will not return anything, only undefined.

I want the data please help me.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw an issue with a callback

```
.then(response => {
     response.json(); 
     // No explicit return then this function will return undefined
})
```

It should be

```
.then(response => {
     return response.json(); // this returns whatever returned from response.json()
})
```

or

```
.then(response => response.json())
```